# Adding data to scala WrappedArray in Java

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the below scala Row which I am getting as part of a JavaRdd.map() call in Java code.

```
["A",4,[WrappedArray(["B"],["C"]),WrappedArray(["D"])]]
```

Schema :

```
{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"id","nullable":false,"type":"string","metadata":{}},{"name":"mid","nullable":false,"type":"long","metadata":{}},{"name":"cr","nullable":false,"type":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"psd","type":{"type":"array","elementType":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"cid","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]},"containsNull":true},"nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"pqd","type":{"type":"array","elementType":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"cid","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]},"containsNull":true},"nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]},"metadata":{}}]}
```

I want to create a new Row with the contents of the above row just adding string "X" to the internal elements of the WrappedArray.

```
["A",4,[WrappedArray(["X", "B"],["X", "C"]),WrappedArray(["X", D"])]]
```

Schema :

```
{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"id","nullable":false,"type":"string","metadata":{}},{"name":"mid","nullable":false,"type":"long","metadata":{}},{"name":"cr","nullable":false,"type":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"psd","type":{"type":"array","elementType":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"cid","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"renamed","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]},"containsNull":true},"nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"pqd","type":{"type":"array","elementType":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"cid","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"renamed","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]},"containsNull":true},"nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]},"metadata":{}}]}
```

How do you create the new Row by adding extra data to the existing struct inside the WrappedArray.

Answer (score 1):

[WrappedArray](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.8/scala/collection/mutable/WrappedArray.html) is an array-like type in Scala. You can create a new WrappedArray by appending an element like this, and then you can update the object:

```
val arr = new WrappedArray.ofRef(Array("a", "b", "c"))
val newArr = arr :+ "d"
```